# ShareX No audio source options in ShareX

Tags: windows-10, audio

I've got a new machine and I forget how to get the audio working for the microphone. Googled of course, all screen shots show options under "Audio" drop-down, but as the following pic shows, my only option is "None":

[image: What am i forgetting?]

What am i forgetting? I hit the "Install recorder devices" button, restarted...

Help!

Answer (score 2):

ach, just try recording a screen capture (vid), it'll ask you to install something something `ffmpeg`, close it, restart, then you'll have mic options.

Comment: This was a head scratcher for me too!